# Unity Fill Amount, Stop Animation Once Condition Is Met

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have a image that starts off with a fill of 0. Then once a Boolean is true, it runs some code that fills the image to a specific amount. My problem is that I am adding a condition to check if the fill amount is met, but the fill amount goes beyond the max amount.

```
private void Update() {
  if (update) {
    if (icon.fillAmount < icon.fillAmount + amount) {
      icon.fillAmount += amount * Time.deltaTime;
      Debug.Log(icon.fillAmount);
    } else update = false;
  }
}
```

In my code, I have an update boolean, and when it is true, it checks if the fill amount less than the maximum fill amount. If that is false, then it runs a line of code to increment the fill amount smoothly, then it logs the fill amount, otherwise it changes the update boolean to false. But, for example if `amount = 0.5f`, when I log the `fillAmount`, it does over `amount`. I think it has to do with the `Time.deltaTime`, but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Mathf.MoveTowards` to achieve what you want. According to Unity3D [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html) this function:

> **Moves a value current towards target.**
>
> This is essentially the same as Mathf.Lerp but instead **the function
>   will ensure that the speed never exceeds maxDelta**. Negative values of
>   maxDelta pushes the value away from target.

```
  if (update) {
    if (icon.fillAmount < 1) {
      icon.fillAmount = Mathf.MoveTowards(icon.fillAmount, 1, amount * Time.deltaTime);
      Debug.Log(icon.fillAmount);
    } else update = false;
  }
```

Comment: After reading the documentation, and trying it myself, I do not understand how to implement it.`icon.fillAmount = Mathf.MoveTowards(icon.fillAmount, icon.fillAmount + amount, amount * Time.deltaTime);
    update = false;` That is my code. When I ran it, it does not animate at all now. PS That code is what's inside the `if` statement

Comment: Try `icon.fillAmount = Mathf.MoveTowards(icon.fillAmount, 1, amount * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: You should also change your if statement. Check my answer. Amount should be a value between 0 and 1.